# Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`. , Failed to install the app

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h6qw.png)

Im new to React-Native and this is driving me insane, I just want to launch the project in the and view the project in the emulator so I can just start coding, I have tried downloading the latest version of JDK, which is apparently not even needed since android studio comes bundled with its own version & also how do I know what version of JDK my android studio comes bundled with ? 
I have been trying to fix this for days now, I even got Blue screen of death when after I messed around with the enviroment variables so now I am desperate and want someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please don't post error messages and whatnot in an image. That is highly discouraged. Please put the error message in the post itself. See [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12708583).

Comment: Ok sry, this is my first time posting here, I thought it would be more clear to just post a screenshot but those reasons make sense.

Comment: Ok, no prob. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62334677/edit) your post to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

React native install app on a single running device. Make sure your emulator is in running condition 
check all connected devices which are eligible for installing using a command

`adb devices`

one device at a time

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JDK path for android and ios, if all things are correct the see the project files in the project.

Then run your project.

I hope it runs.